# How to make the infowindow appear depending upon the space it already have and not move the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am displaying few locations in google maps. I refresh these locations if a user zoom in/out or drags the map. Now the issue is if i click on the marker of a location then the info window opens up and drags the map if it doesn't have any space to show. This dragging causes my locations to be refreshed and hence my marker vanishes.

I tried  `disableAutoPan: true` but then the info window is not seen only. Is there any way that the info window auto adjust itself. is there any way to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to indicate when the refresh should be ignored, for example:

```
// Global var
var ignoreRefresh = false;

google.maps.addListener(marker,'click', function(){
  ignoreRefresh = true;
  infoWindow.setContent('Hello');
  infoWindow.open(map,marker);
})

function refresh(){
  if (ignoreRefresh) {
    ignoreRefresh = false;
    return;
  }
  //...
  //do your normal refresh of data
  //...

}
```

Comment: This will stop the refresh of the stores... i have already done that... But i dont want to make the map move because of some business logic... So thats why i want to adjust the info window... How to do that?

Comment: It will only prevent refresh when the user has clicked a marker and opened an infoWindow. Otherwise it will refresh normally.

Comment: hmmmm... And how to adjust the infowindow?

Comment: I don't know what you want to adjust. Note that your question is actually two questions in one post. You said "This dragging causes my locations to be refreshed and hence my marker vanishes.", this will prevent the marker from vanishing.